# DataGridView RowValidating fires after selecting another control. Any workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Using the RowValidating events works fine.

But if i click somewhere in the datagridview without changing the row the event is always fireed after selecting another contorl.

**Sample-1 (correct):**

```
Selecting a Row -> Selecting a Textbox -> Selecting antoher Row
                                          |->RowValidating raised
```

**Sample-2 (incorrect):**

```
Selecting a Row -> Clicking the Columnheader -> Selecting a Textbox  ->  Selecting antoher Row
                                                |->RowValidating raised  |->RowValidating raised
```

**Sample-3 (incorrect):**

```
Selecting a Row -> Clicking empty Area -> Selecting a Textbox  ->  Selecting antoher Row
                                          |->RowValidating raised  |->RowValidating raised
```

Is there any way to only get RowInvalidating before a row is realy changeing?

I already tried to override `SetSelectedRowCore` and was able the cancel the selection change, but the datagridview sends `EndEdit()` to the Binding before `SetSelectedRowCore` is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a little dirty workaround:

```
    private void dataGridView_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) {
        Point pos = dataGridView.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hi = dataGridView.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y);
        if (hi.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell && hi.RowIndex != e.RowIndex) {
            e.Cancel = !AllowChangeCurrent(); //Check if changing selection is allowed
        }
    }
```

First I get the Current mouse position in DataGridView.

Afterward I check if a cell if clicked. (False -> Finished)

At least I check if the clicked cell/row is not the current (False -> Finished | True -> Validate)